# SQL Server problem with CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 103)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

today is 08/06/2020 (monday 8th, 6 june, 2020)

when I convert date with getdate()

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 103) as deb
```

It show **08/06/2020** OK

WHen i type

```
select convert(varchar, CONVERT(DATE, '08/06/2020') ,  103) as deb
```

It show **06/08/2020** THis is not ok ....

WHy when i type getdate() the convert is ok dd/MM/yyyy but with convert date is like MM/dd/yyyy

thx for help

Comment: This is why using unambiguous date formats is important. In SQL Server, regardless data type and language, that's `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnn`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `style` parameter when you convert from text:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(DATE, '08/06/2020', 103),  103) AS deb
```

Note, that it's important to specify the [length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) for target `varchar` data type (the default value is `30`):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(DATE, '08/06/2020', 103),  103) AS deb
```

Comment: If it's working, you should accept it as the solution, @guillaumezac .